# I would like to add and play video in my html mail , but not able to find the correct way to do it

Tags: html, email, video

I would like to add and play video in my html mail , but  not able to find the correct way to do it .
i have created many templates and send to my mail , but whenever i press the play button available on the image it will land me to my server page where my video is available .

please help me out in figure out the way to play video in my HTML mail.

Comment: How are you doing it now? Can you share some code. You might need to include (attachment) the video in your email?

Comment: is there any way to fetch a video inside  html file without landing it to new page.

Answer (score 1):

Video is not fully supported in all email clients. More info, and a technique of how to do it, can be found [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2905/html5-and-video-in-email/)